# Laravel Form Request Validation with switch statement

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel application and am using the Form Request validation.

I have implemented the following:

```
 public function rules(){
      return [
            'item_name'=>'required',
            'item_description'=> 'required',
        ];
    }
```

In the controller I have the following:

```
public function storeItem(storeItem $request) {
        $validated = $request->validated();
         ...
         ...     

        }
    }
```

This works correctly, but because for certain items not all $request variables are required, I would like to implement a switch statement as follows:

```
public function rules()
{
    $item_type = $this->route('item_type');
    switch($item_type) {
        case 'type1':
             return [
                'item_name'=>'required',
                'item_description'=> 'required',
            ];
            break;
         case 'type2':
             return [
                'item_name'=>'required',
                'item_amount'=> 'required',
                'item_favorite'=> 'required',
            ];
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm getting back the following error:

> Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of
>   the type array, null given

This error message seems to suggest I'm not returning an array, but I do have the return statements per switch case so not sure why I see this eeror message.

Any idea how this could be solved? If a switch statement is not the good option, any other idea?

Comment: `$request` of type `storeItem` ?

Comment: Yes, documebted here (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation). It mentions "All you need to do is type-hint the request on your controller method". That part is working fine. It's the Switch statement that causes issues

Comment: Fair enough. Your switch case itself has the string `'item_type'`. You probably want to pass a variable there, else it won't match with any case and defaults to nothing.

Comment: That was a left over still, I edited the original post. Issue still exists

Comment: What if `$item_type` is neither `type1` nor `type2`?

Comment: You should add a `default` case or `return array();` at the end of your method.

Comment: Also, if there are only 2 conditions/values, I don't see a need for switch.

Comment: `break` after a `return` is trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The default case is there but did not show in the original post. In the meantime I found the solution. My switch case should be based on switch($this->request->get('item_type')).

Comment: Ok, can't catch that since I am unaware about what's going on in the code. Also, you always need to mention the [minimum,complete,verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code to get a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
public function rules()
{
    switch($this->request->get('item_type')) {
        case 'Type1':
             return [
              'item_name'=>'required',
              'item_description'=> 'required',
            ];
            break;
         case 'Type2':
             return [
                 'item_name'=>'required',
                 'item_amount'=> 'required',
                 'item_favorite'=> 'required',
            ];
            break;

        default:
            return [
                'item_name'=>'required',
            ];
    }
}
```